# checking file extension with regular expression

Tags: java, regex, jfilechooser

I am writing a program that opens a file and loads all the file contents into a JTextArea. I want to restrict users from being able to open different file formats. The formats i want to accept include: .js .php .html .asmx .htm .css basically any format readable in a web browser.

What is the best way to do this?

Should I use a regular expression to check if the file's name matches my criteria or is there a simpler solution?

Here is kind of what I had in mind:

```
String fileExtensions = "(.js|.php|.html|.asmx|.htm|.css)$"; // $ end of line regex
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
int returnValue = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);

if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
    String fileName = file.toString();
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(fileExtensions);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(fileName);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        openAndReadFile(); // opens the file and outputs contents
    } else {
        // prompt the user to open a different file
    }
} else {
    // do nothing because cancel was pressed
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have to use regex? The most appropriate way to do this would be a `FileNameExtensionFilter`

Example (from the [FileNameExtensionFilter API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileNameExtensionFilter.html)):

```
FileFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("JPEG file", "jpg", "jpeg");
JFileChooser fileChooser = ...;
fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);
```

Comment: No i don't have to. I am looking for the most efficient means of checking the filename for these types of extensions. Did not know i could use an extension filter i will have to look into this, thanks in advance.

Comment: @inner_class7 classic [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) :). Anyway is correct/preferred approach.

Comment: One more quick question? With this can you create a multi - level or multi extension filter or do i Have to create multiple filters each time i want to check the file's name?

Comment: @inner_class7 you can create something like `new FileNameExtensionFilter("MyHTMLFormats", "js", "php", "html", "asmx", "htm", "css");` and use it as filter.

Comment: @inner_class7 This may interest you. To remove `"AllFiles"` filter you will have to invoke `fileChooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);` and to make `MyHTMLFormats` default filter use `setFileFilter(filter);` instead of `addChoosableFileFilter(filter);`